# What is the terminal command line in OSX Mojave to find the folder where screenshots are saved?

Tags: macos, screenshot

What Terminal command in OSX will show the path where screenshots are set to save? I am trying to find a screenshot I took last week on my Macbook Pro running OSX Mojave. There are no screenshots saved on my desktop which I understand to be the default save location. Therefore I am thinking I changed the save location but don't remember where.

I already tried searching for 'Screenshots' in Finder but this only shows screenshots taken before Oct 2018 even though I have taken many since then, including in the last hour. Same for the 'Screenshots' folder in my Dropbox.

I also verified that the screenshot shortcut I used Command+Shift+4 is correctly set to 'Save picture of selected area a file' and 'Copy picture of selected area to the clipboard'. I verified this in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > ScreenShot. And successfully took a screenshot with this shortcut just now.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on macOS Mojave 10.14.3:

```
defaults read com.apple.screencapture location
```

**Sample Output**

```
~/Desktop
```